# Next JS - Removing useless parameter from a GetServerSideProps wrapper error

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I'm refactoring my GetServerSideProps wrapper that will check if the user have a valid cookie and if the user level obtained from DB is enough to access the page.

It's working as expected now, but i want to separate the the cookie check and the user level check.

But removing the unused pageLvl paramenter from the wrapper and from it's call in the page's GetServerSideProps is giving me error.

As it now and working:

```
// myWrapper.ts

// Wrapper with the unused parameter pageLvl
// baseAuthenticated is the core function but it's not affected by pageLvl paramenter anymore so it's useless to post it.

export const authenticatedSSR = (pageLvl:number,callback:Function) => async (ctx:Context) => {
    return baseAuthenticated(callback, ctx, 'SSR');
}
```

```
// index.js ... i'll be working to make it in TypeScript but not now

const thisPageLvl = 100; // example value

async function HomePageSS({ query }, user) {
    // my stuff here ...

 }

export const getServerSideProps = authenticatedSSR(thisPageLvl,HomePageSS);
```

As modified and not working:

```
// myWrapper.ts

// Wrapper without the unused parameter pageLvl
// baseAuthenticated is the core function but it's not affected by pageLvl paramenter anymore so it's useless to post it.

export const authenticatedSSR = (callback:Function) => async (ctx:Context) => {
    return baseAuthenticated(callback, ctx, 'SSR');
}
```

```
// index.js ... i'll be working to make it in TypeScript but not now

const thisPageLvl = 100; // example value

async function HomePageSS({ query }, user) {
    // my stuff here ...

 }

// removed thisPageLvl
export const getServerSideProps = authenticatedSSR(HomePageSS);
```

Error:

```
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/clean.js:8:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$
./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js
./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3-binding.js
./node_modules/sqlite3/lib/sqlite3.js
./utils/DbHelper.ts
./utils/Classes/packaging.ss.js
./utils/SSRHelpers.js
./pages/index.js

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

the traced modules have nothing to do with the generated error, it's generated only by removing the parameter.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any unused imports in `pages/index.js`.